# Mapping keys to objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

What would be the best way to map `keys` to `classes`? Names are familiar, but not the same. I know that `data_to_object` implementation with `ifs` is bad, but it's just to get the point.

```py
errors = {
    'BadRequest': {
        'title': "Some title",
        'description': "Some description"
    },
    'NotFoundError': {
        'title': "Some title2",
        'description': "Some description2"
    }
}
    

class HttpException(Exception):
    title: str 
    description: str 


class HttpNotFound(HttpException):
    ...

 
class HTTPBadRequest(HttpException):
    ...
    

def data_to_object(errors):
    data = list()
    for key, value in errors.items():
        if key == 'NotFoundError':
            data.append(HttpNotFound(title=value['title'], value=['description']))
        if key == 'BadRequest':
            data.append(HTTPBadRequest(title=value['title'], value=['description']))
    return data

list_of_objects = data_to_object(errors)
```

Expected result:

```py
list_of_objects = [HttpNotFound(), HTTPBadRequest())
```

Comment: There are several syntax issues. Please validate your code.

Comment: @trincot yeh sorry, fixed it

Comment: `value=['description']` is also wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just create a dictionary that maps a key to a class:

```
map = {
    'BadRequest': HTTPBadRequest,
    'NotFoundError': HttpNotFound
}

def data_to_object(errors):
    return [map[key](title=value['title'],description=value['description'])
           for key, value in errors.items() if key in map]
```